# Unable to execute update statement in ucanaccess

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ucanaccess

I have a connection to a Microsoft Access database. Once I make the connection I'm trying to get everything from that table I'm accessing with the following query.

```
ResultSet rSet = stmt.executeQuery("Select * FROM DraftNightQuery")
```

As far as I am able to tell, that works fine. I then have a while loop that runs as long as rSet.nex().

In my while loop I'm trying to run an update statement which looks like this:

```
connec.executeUpdate("UPDATE DraftNightQuery SET OwnerID='"+x+"' WHERE Last='"+split[0]+"' AND First='"+split[1]+ "' ");
```

and it's throwing this error:

```
 net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or TRUNCATE not permitted for table or view
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the update query itself, however that worked for ODBC, and from what I can tell on the UCanAccess website it should work for this as well.

edit:

SQL for query throwing `PUBLIC.NZ(DOUBLE)` error:

```
SELECT TotalStats.ID, Players.First, Players.Last, (Nz([TotalStats].[W]*25))-(Nz([TotalStats].[L]*5))+(Nz([TotalStats].[PG]*10))+(Nz([TotalStats].[QS]*10))+(Nz([TotalStats].[SV]*20))-(Nz([TotalStats].[BS]*5))+(Nz([TotalStats].[Holds]*15))+(Nz([TotalStats].[GF]*5))+(Nz([TotalStats].[Innings]*3))-(Nz([TotalStats].[PH]*1))-(Nz([TotalStats].[ER]*2))-(Nz([TotalStats].[PHR]*8))-(Nz([TotalStats].[PBB]*3))+(Nz([TotalStats].[PK]*5))-(Nz([TotalStats].[PHB]*3))-(Nz([TotalStats].[WP]*1))+(Nz([TotalStats].[CG]*50))+(Nz([TotalStats].[ShO]*75)) AS Points, Owners.TeamName, Players.OwnerID, Players.PositionType
FROM Owners RIGHT JOIN (Players LEFT JOIN TotalStats ON Players.ID = TotalStats.ID) ON Owners.OwnerID = Players.OwnerID
WHERE (((Players.PositionType)="Pitch") AND ((Players.DraftStatus)="Drafted"))
ORDER BY (Nz([TotalStats].[W]*25))-(Nz([TotalStats].[L]*5))+(Nz([TotalStats].[PG]*10))+(Nz([TotalStats].[QS]*10))+(Nz([TotalStats].[SV]*20))-(Nz([TotalStats].[BS]*5))+(Nz([TotalStats].[Holds]*15))+(Nz([TotalStats].[GF]*5))+(Nz([TotalStats].[Innings]*3))-(Nz([TotalStats].[PH]*1))-(Nz([TotalStats].[ER]*2))-(Nz([TotalStats].[PHR]*8))-(Nz([TotalStats].[PBB]*3))+(Nz([TotalStats].[PK]*5))-(Nz([TotalStats].[PHB]*3))-(Nz([TotalStats].[WP]*1))+(Nz([TotalStats].[CG]*50))+(Nz([TotalStats].[ShO]*75)) DESC;
```

Comment: Don't use the same statement object for the query and the update.

Comment: @gknicker I should specify, once in the loop I again say stmt = con.createStatement.

Is it still better to just use a different variable entirely?

Comment: Yes, definitely. You're still using the other one. It backs the ResultSet.

Comment: I've changed it to `Statement connec = con.createStatement();` and it's still giving the same error. I've also updated my original post to reflect the changed code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Sorry, I don't know. It sounds like your access database file is set to read-only, or perhaps a bug in the driver.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It would appear one possibility  has to do with a lack of primary key, which is something I believe is due to the fact that DraftNightQuery is a table generated by SQL in Access.

Comment: Ah, there you go. You can generate the primary key by SQL in Access also.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but what's the best way to generate a primary key through SQL? I believe I would know how to do it with a create table statement, however because this is a query gathering data from multiple tables, I'm unsure.

Comment: Is the file an .mdb file in Access 97 format?

Comment: @GordThompson Not sure I understand the question totally, but it's `.accdb` in Access 2013. Although I'm relatively certain the database was originally created in Access 2010

Comment: Try running "console.bat" (in the same folder as the UCanAccess .jar file), entering the full path to the .accdb file when prompted, and see if the output gives you any clues as to what might be wrong.

Comment: I believe I've fixed a few errors, but I'm getting stuck on this one as I'm unsure of what it means. `routine signature not found for: PUBLIC.NZ(DOUBLE)` I've updated my post with the code of the query it gives that error for.

Comment: I've recreated the "routine signature not found" error and asked about it on the UCanAccess [help forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/). Have you solved the "INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or TRUNCATE not permitted" issue?

Comment: Not yet. It seems like the `DraftNightQuery` doesn't show up with any errors when I run `console.bat` so I'm not sure if it's something that is unique to that specific query or not. Hoping that the routine signature error will help if we get it sorted.

Comment: I have been able to recreate your "INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or TRUNCATE not permitted" issue and have reported it in the UCanAccess help forum [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/ab18b188/). In the meantime you might consider altering your query to UPDATE the [Players] table directly instead of doing the UPDATE through the saved SELECT query.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at updating the player table to see if that will work.

Answer (score 3):

I can see two different issues:

-An issue with the nz(double). I just implemented nz(text), so it's a lack of implementation to be fixed in the next version (which I'll release ASAP, likely during the next week).

-The second one is about using an update sql statement on a query.
Access select queries aren't physical tables  even if they may look like.
They are just select queries.
If you execute an update on a select queries access can update the data in the underlying tables: the tables used in the query and  involved in the update. So it's something sophisticated that the Jet engine can do and that may also lead to bad and unclear SQL code, if improperly used. UCanAccess relies on Hsqldb that in many cases doesn't allow update statements on views. 
So you have to call the SQL update statement directly on the table you want to update.

Notice that hsqldb supports some advanced features from SQL 2003 standard , (like MERGE INTO),  that work with UCanAccess and in several cases may work  as  "smart"(but standard) substitute solution for your requirements (see this [thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/90c14989/)).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I ended up following @GordThompson's suggestion and just edit the original table, which seems to do the job well enough. While the NZ(double) error still exists, I'm not currently attempting to do anything with that query, so it's nothing pressing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update a resulset with an stardard SELECT query using UCanAccess. You have two options:

1. Using a PreparedStatement with this parameters ("SELECT * FROM YourTableName", ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT). Execute to generate a Resultset with ExecuteQuery(). Finally, update your Resultset calling this two methods: UpdateString (if field type is String) and UpdateRow.
2. Use 2 Statements:

```html
    st1 = conn.createStatement();
    rs = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable");
    while(rs.next()) {
        st2 = conn.createStatement();
        st2.executeUpdate("UPDATE MyTable SET MyField='New Value' WHERE MyField2 LIKE 'Condition'");
    }
```